# Is there any limit to the Number of Steps for Load Test in the SOAP UI free version?

Tags: soapui, load-testing

I am trying to perform the load Test from `SOAPUI free version (5.2.1)`.

I have a Test case with 15 steps which have different Rest Requests. I have created a Load test for the same and when i run the load test, all the requests are not getting executed. Only first six request gets executed. I have tried using different strategy along with different varying thread counts and limits but the result is same. only first six requests gets executed till the limit ends.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your results I see a lot of errors. 
- First try to get rid of those.

Is it possible the test is running out of time?
- Try increasing the timelimit to a much larger value.

Also try a simpler strategy (like 'Simple') and see what happens.