# Run all requests in SOAP UI Load test

Tags: load, soapui

I've 28 requests in total(combining Delay and regular test caseB, C, A...), when I give the limit as 56 for total runs for a Simple Strategy with single thread, only first few ran successfully but the rest remained untouched. I tried it couple of times but still couldn't able to proceed further. I'm using free SOAP UI 4.6.4 version. Though I see the errors in the first two requests, I want to proceed further as there are no dependencies with the previous requests.

[image]

I looked into the [Is there any limit to the Number of Steps for Load Test in the SOAP UI free version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917350/is-there-any-limit-to-the-number-of-steps-for-load-test-in-the-soap-ui-free-vers), but couldnt get any result. Basically I'm facing the same issue.

How can I make all the requests do get triggered, even in case of errors.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to schitch off the option "Abort test if an error occurs" in the **Test Case** settings (NOT in the Load Test settings). See the picture bellow.

[image]

Please note that you have 56 rounds in total, but when the 2 runs failed at step B, only 54 test case runs continue. At step A 54 runs failed and were aborted, so there is nothing left to continue.